# Why am I getting this error: Object Variable or With block variable not set?

Tags: vba, excel

I have found out what causes this error but I cannot pinpoint where it is coming from in my code.  I even tested this macro in a separate worksheet in excel and it worked but in this worksheet it is not working.  Can anyone guess as to why or offer any workarounds? I put a comment on the line with the error. Assume data is put in correctly.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim startDate As Date, endDate As Date, reason As String, name As String
    name = InputBox("Please enter the name of the SLG as appears in column 1 on the worksheet:")
    startDate = InputBox("Please enter the start date in MM/DD/YYYY format:")
    endDate = InputBox("Please enter the end date in MM/DD/YYYY format:")
    reason = InputBox("Please short description for the absence:")

    Dim rng1 As Range, columnNumberStart As Integer, rowNumber As Integer, columnNumberEnd As Integer, test1 As String, test2 As String

    Worksheets("FY-15 Schedule").Activate

    Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find(name)
    rowNumber = rng1.Row

    Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find(startDate) 
    columnNumberStart = rng1.Column 'Says Error is on this line

    Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find(endDate)
    columnNumberEnd = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find(endDate).Column

    test1 = Cells(rowNumber, columnNumberStart).Address
    test2 = Cells(rowNumber, columnNumberEnd).Address

    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng2 = Range(test1, test2)


    rng2.Value = reason

End Sub
```

Comment: what happens if the user doesn't input a date in the correct format (or a date at all?) or if for some reason there is no "Active" sheet

Comment: I apologize but I am assuming all data is input correctly and it still doesnt work

Comment: What happens if you do this `Dim startDate as Variant`?

Comment: @guitarthrower same problem.

Comment: Seems like obvious source of this error is that the `.Find` method has returned `Nothing` to the range object, so then you are essentially doing `Nothing.Column`, which is an error.  Google for help on "finding date values" in Excel.  I don't remember how to do it off the top of my head...

Comment: are you 100% certain that the date exists in the sheet?

Comment: You know I bet I know what it is but I will test it first.  I have several copies of the same workbook and the text may not be formatted as a date in the cells themselves.  Maybe it will typecast it if it isnt but it is worth a shot to see what happens.

Comment: It appears that when searching for dates in Excel (and it's formatted as a date) your search string must be in `m/d/yyyy` format.

Comment: hmmm... I am going to play around with that idea.  I will get back to you guys.  Something is weird because it works in other copies just not my most recent one and I havent changed that block of code.

Comment: @billmann see my answer. There are at least **two** possible sources for this error: 1) the date is improperly formatted in the VBA (not the sheet) and/or 2) the date doesn't exist on the sheet.  I don't get an error whether the date is formatted as date or as string shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! The problem was this:  It was not finding the dates because the dates were being generated by a formula!!  My first date was manually typed in but the rest of them were a fill series from the second cell which was `A2=A1+1`  and all the way down the line. I wanted it that way so the start date could be changed but for some reason excel was not recognizing those as dates!?! How weird?!?!

Problem solved though.  What you said was correct about it not finding the date but appearance wise when looking at the spreadsheet it is there in plain sight but when looking at the cells their values were formulas.

Comment: Great! Excel has some difficulty knowing that you want the `Find` method to return the result of an evaluated formula, it's not that it doesn't recognize the value as a date, only that the `Find` method is not suited for that without some tweaking, I think.  Good job for finding the workaround :)

Comment: If you're using Find you should specify all the relevant arguments, such as whether to look in values or formulas. Remember that these can persist between uses of Find (both in code and in the UI) so they may not be set to what you need.

Comment: @Rory thank you very much I did not look at all the optional parameters/arguments.  I should research the methods I use before I use them from now on.  That could save me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 3):

First, explicitly coerce the date from the inputbox input:

```
startDate = CDate(InputBox("Please enter the start date in MM/DD/YYYY format:"))
```

And do the same for the other date field.

Then, there is still possible source of this same error: when the `.Find` method has returned `Nothing` to the range object, (e.g., the date is not found/doesn't exist in the sheet) then you are essentially doing `Nothing.Column`, which is an error.

If the date does not exist in the sheet, this will *always* raise an error, which you could trap like this, or use GoTo statements to return to the inputbox, etc...

```
Set rng3 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find(startDate) 
If rng3 Is Nothing Then 
    MsgBox "Start date" & Cstr(startDate) & " not found!", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
End If
columnNumberStart = rng1.Column
```

Comment: I did some quick testing and Excel requires the search string be in M/D/YYYY format.

Comment: @guitarthrower or `CDate` will coerce that date to proper format for the `Find` method.  Cheers~

Comment: So it does. Brilliant!

Comment: thanks guys but I think it has something to do with the worksheet I am using.  I tried your solution and used the debugger and no luck there.  I have another worksheet that it does work with but they are identical for all intents and purposes.  Just some different data.  All formatted the same.  I am stumped

Comment: any chance you can upload a sheet with a few rows of example dates and your macro, to Google Docs or Dropbox? I can probably look at it later tonight...